# Steam badge didn't level up

Tags: steam

I got my 5th game on Steam and the game badge didn't level up, it is still at the 1+ Game badge.

Why didn't the badge level up?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just gain an additional badge instead of changing one you've already earned.

Comment: @Broneironaut nope, it's the same badge.

Comment: @Avery Its not because my friend has a 5+ game badge.

Comment: Did you literally *just* buy the game now?  Have you at least received the receipt for the purchase in your email?  Perhaps it takes time to finish processing the sale before the badge gets updated

Comment: @TheDoggo no, what I meant is, the badge upgrades, you don't get a separate badge.

Answer (score 3):

Is the game count on your profile 5 or are you counting the ones on game list?

Game count on profile counts some games less (for example F2P games aren't counted but some paid games aren't counted either, I don't know why they're not counted), and the badge is awarded based on the number on your profile.

---

If the game count on your profile is 5, then you have encountered a bug and you probably just need to wait a bit for steam servers to settle down a bit (it's sale season) or just buy another game and see if that works.